# Как заставить модуль googletrans убрать ненужные "системные" слова при выводе перевода?

Tags: python

Всем привет! Пишу двух-язычного (ru, en) телеграм бота. Код полностью кидать не буду, а покажу на похожем примере:

```
from googletrans import Translator

tr = Translator()

text = 'Привет, знатоки, помогите!'

print(tr.translate(text))
```

**При выводе в консоли виден данный результат (пишу полностью):**
*Translated(src=ru, dest=en, text=Hi experts, help!, pronunciation=None, extra_data="{'translat...")*

**Такой результат пишется и в самом телеграм боте (пишу полностью):**
*Translated(src=ru, dest=en, text=Hello again Cheburkek, I'm a Cool Pictures bot!
I will help you find interesting pictures to your liking. To get started, select your mood from the tiles at the bottom of the screen., pronunciation=[[]], extra_data="{'translat...")*

Помогите пожалуйста. Кто знает, как убрать эти "Translated(src=ru, dest=en, text..." и т.д.?

Надеюсь, вам всё понятно. Если нет - пишите, допишу подробнее. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте `print(tr.translate(text).text)` А вообще у меня в `Google Colab` ваш код у меня с ошибкой падает, видимо под какой-то старый питон версия.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь! Все исправилось)

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа, отметьте его как подходящий )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Translated(src=ru, dest=en, text=Hello again Cheburkek...
```

Это выглядит как некая структура с полями `src`, `dest`, `text` и т.д. Нужно просто взять через точку нужное вам поле этой структуры, я полагаю, что это `text`:

```py
print(tr.translate(text).text)
                        ^^^^^
```